# Dynamic html dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns on a HTML form. I am trying to get the second dropdowns answers to be dynamic based upon the first box.
So if dropdown 1 is “1” dropdown two will have options “a” “b” “c”, if dropdown 1 is “2” dropdown 2 will have “d” “e” “f”.

What is the best way to achieve this, ideally with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this method http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm but have had no luck with that. There were some others i tried but im afreid i have lost the files to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you use ajax to post the first option and get the options for the second select.

Example:

```
<script>
function onSelect1Change(){
$.post("url" ,{
        value: $("#select1").val()
          }, function(data) {
         $("#select2").html(data);
    }); 
}
</script>

<select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="onSelect1Change">...</select>
<select id="select2" name="select2" ></select>
```

In your back-end you check the `$_POST['value']` and output some `<option></option>` tags.

Comment: Thank you, took me a while of tweaking however this is working now. Tweaking was my data, not your code.